# Функции date и mktime

Tags: php, алгоритм, unixtimestamp

Как получить количество дней и в в месяце (t) и день недели (w) на 9223372036854775807 (максимальное 64 integer) год? Пробую делать через mktime и date - ничего не выходит:

```
date('d.m.Y',mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 1, 9223372036854775807) )
```

Возвращает "30.11.-0001". Я пробовал найти закономерность, чтобы уменьшить 9223372036854775807 год до реальных, чтобы был меньше 2038. Но закономерность нормальную удалось найти только у высокосных годов (там календарь повторяется каждые 28 лет). Цель такая, чтобы выдавать дату на любой год, максимальный год 9223372036854775807. Может есть решения на php или хотя бы какой алгоритм здесь можно применить?

Comment: Если уж вам хочется периодичности григорианского календаря - то это 400 лет...

Comment: Только учтите, что даже если солнечная система к тому времени бы и существовала, а продолжительность года оставалась бы прежней, то расхождение календаря от реального времени было бы больше 10^14 лет :) - так что вряд ли бы григорианский календарь просуществовал столько...

Comment: Да, спасибо!) Оказалось 9999 лет достаточно, с этим помогли функции php Calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная функция  cal_days_in_month();
Date с флагом - w, t - это ваш случай.

```
if (!function_exists('cal_days_in_month'))
{
function cal_days_in_month($calendar, $month, $year)
{
    return date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
}
}
if (!defined('CAL_GREGORIAN'))
define('CAL_GREGORIAN', 1);


$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2018); // 28
echo "Всего {$number} дней в Феврале 2018 года";


echo date("w", mktime(0,0,0,12,1,2004));
```

Comment: Да, супер, это работает. Про функции Calendar не знал, спасибо!)